# Boolean wff is satisfiable?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, automata

Definition:

> A Boolean wff is satisfiable if and only if it is true for at least one assignment of truth values to the variables it contains.

Question:

The wff P v $\neg$Q is satisfiable. It is True if either P is True or Q is False.

The operator is OR. Why is this satisfiable? I understand P implies Q, but not the other way around. If P is true then we satisfy the statement. But if it's false, and Q is true, then the negative of Q would also be false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When checking for satisfiability, you *choose* the values of $P$ and $Q$ to be true or false, so as to make the final proposition true.  If the proposition is insastifiable, it means no combination of assignment of $P$ and $Q$ will make the proposition true.

So letting $P = \top$ and $Q = \top$ satisfies $P \vee \neg Q$ that is $P \vee \neg Q$ is satisfiable.

Now be careful $P \vee\neg Q$ is a rewriting of the implication operator in the other direction : $Q \Rightarrow P$.  Indeed if $Q$ is true, then so must $P$.  But if $Q$ is false, there are no requirements on $P$.  Thus you can write the implication $( Q \wedge P) \vee \neg Q$, which can be distributed to 
\begin{equation}
  (Q \vee \neg Q) \wedge (P \vee \neg Q) = \top \wedge (P \vee \neg Q) = P \vee \neg Q
\end{equation}

Comment: So am I correct that 3/4 times combining P and Q assignments for P∨¬Q evaluates as true? And all we need for it to be satisfiable is for it to evaluate as true once?

Comment: Yes that's all you need.  The fun part is when you try to satisfy a whole bunch of propositions at once.  E.g. The pair $\{Q, P\vee\neg Q\}$ is only satisfied by setting both $P$ and $Q$ to true.